# data repeating when two tables are joined in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, join

[image]

I tried to fetch data using joins and the data is repeating,

The controller code is:

```
public function searchjobs2()
{
    //$id=$_SESSION['id'];
    $lan = $_POST["picke"]; //var_dump($id);die(); 
    $value['list']=$this->Free_model->get_jobs($lan);//var_dump($value);die();
    $this->load->view('free/header');
    $this->load->view('free/searchjobs2',$value);
}
```

And the model:

```
public function get_jobs($lan)
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from("tbl_work_stats");
    $this->db->join("tbl_work", "tbl_work.login_id = tbl_work_stats.login_id",'inner');
    $this->db->where("language LIKE '%$lan%'");
    // $this->db->where('tbl_work_stats.login_id',$id);
    $this->db->order_by('insertdate','asc');

    $query=$this->db->get()->result_array();//var_dump($query);die();
    return $query;
}
```

I have used

```
foreach ($list as $row){
    ...
}
```

for listing.

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample and the expected  result

Comment: use group by keyword to the purpose whatever you want.

Comment: group by work title.

Comment: Please provide your database and also the snippet which you are using in view-side.

Answer (score 0):

Using distinct will remove duplicate fields:

```
$this->db->distinct();
```

Comment: using distinct isn't a good idea unless you know why you are getting multiple rows.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, your query has ambiguity, and an error in the join statement, also your where like is part of the problem, I would recommend trying this even do there are some missing info, find out wich field you need to join from the second table.

```
    public function get_jobs($lan){
$this->db->select("tbl_work_stats.*, tbl_work.fields");
$this->db->from("tbl_work_stats");
$this->db->join("tbl_work", "tbl_work_stats.login_id = tbl_work.login_id","inner");
$this->db->where("tbl_work.language LIKE", "%" . $lan . "%" );
$this->db->order_by("tbl_work_stats.insertdate","asc");
$query=$this->db->get()->result_array();
return $query;}
```

Answer (score -1):

do you mean to join on login_id? 
I am guessing that is the user logging in and it is the same for many entries of tbl_work_stats and tbl_work.

you didn't post your schema, , but login_id doesn't seem like right thing to join on.  how about something like tbl_work.id = tbl_work_stats.tbl_work_id or similar?

also CI $db returns self, so you can do:

```
public function get_jobs(string $lan):array
{
  return $this->db->select()
     ->from('tbl_work_stats')
     ->join('tbl_work','tbl_work.id = tbl_work_stats.work_id')
     ->like('language',$lan)
     ->order_by('insertdate')
     ->get()
     ->result_array();
 }
```